# golang get cookies simplification code

Tags: go

I want to learn to write clean and simple code in golang, this is my actual code :

```
if r.Method == "POST" && r.FormValue("pincodeVal") != ""  {
        var cliente, dd, mm, aaaa, email string
        redirectt    := "http://" + r.Host + "/" + GetMD5Hash(randString(10))

        session1, _ := store.Get(r, "loginSession")
        email       = GetSes(session1.Values["email"])

        cliente_cookie, err := r.Cookie("codicecliente")
        if err == nil { cliente = cliente_cookie.Value }

        dd_cookie, err := r.Cookie("dd")
        if err == nil { dd = dd_cookie.Value }

        mm_cookie, err := r.Cookie("mm")
        if err == nil { mm =  mm_cookie.Value }

        aaaa_cookie, err := r.Cookie("aaaa")
        if err == nil { aaaa =  aaaa_cookie.Value }

        pincode := r.FormValue("pincodeVal")

        if cliente == "" || dd == "" || mm == "" || aaaa == "" {
            http.Redirect(w, r, redirectt + "/login.html", 302)
        }
}
```

Does there exist a way to make more this golang code simpler?

Comment: This is off-topic on SO. I suggest you post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to move the replicated code to a function:

```
func cookie(r *http.Request, name string) string {
   c, err := r.Cookie(name)
   if err != nil {
      return ""
   }
   return c.Value
}
```

Use it like this:

```
    cliente := cookie(r, "codicecliente")
    dd := cookie(r, "dd")
    mm := cookie(r, "mm")
    aaaa := cookie(r, "aaaa")
```